# Can't switch from css to scss in create-react-app temple in CodeSandbox

Tags: reactjs, sass, codesandbox

I'm using create-react-app in my project but when I try to use scss instead of css it breaks.
I have tried to install dependencies node-sass and saas-loader - still nothing.
I've also tried to change the temple for parcel but then nothing is rendered.
Can you please help and show me the way to switch to scss in this project?

https://codesandbox.io/s/5y9nr49y44

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

codesandbox does not support sass compile with the create-react-app, see issue: https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/75

Using Parcel template should work, see example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rjj38yzm14  *(kudos to [CompuIves](https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/75#issuecomment-372510526))*

Answer (score -1):

By default create-react-app does not support using css preprocessors (such as scss, less, stylus), so your option if you really want to use .scss in your project is to [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) and use a webpack loader ([sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader)) for this.

Comment: Not true, no need to eject. 
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc